# How to see all Request URLs the server do usage

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, tcpdump

I need to install a software into a server that is not connected to the internet. I'll be able to access a part of internet during one day to do the installation.

They are asking me the url/internet addresses that I'll be needing.

For the time being, my plan was

- Get all the wget and explicit links.
- Get the links for the OS packages with the following command - the example is with `curl` : `apt-get download --print-uris curl`

Nevertheless, I'm afraid that maybe other links are that I'm not aware of (for example when using other commands).

Is there a way to to do a clean installation and to log all the urls the server request throughout the installation ?

A came across this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570391/how-to-see-all-request-urls-the-server-is-doing-final-urls) which is similar but not exactly the same and I can't make it work for my case.
What I tried was to run the following command (in the background)

```
tcdump -i any -A -vv -s 0 | grep -e "GET" -e "Host:" -e "POST" > log &
```

But when using the command `wget stackoverflow.com` there is nothing that gets logged. I have never used `tcpdump` so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Better install from an installation media: https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/installation-media

Comment: I don't think this is a bash, not even a [so] question. `bash` is a language. It should not be confused with any command line. Unless your difficulty is to find a way to pipe your command together or something like that, what you are really looking for is a recommendation for a tool that does this job.

Comment: I know that a single command is, somehow a bash command. Like type `firefox` in the terminal, if that terminal runs bash, is a bash command. Nevertheless we wouldn't consider a question about which web browser to use, and even not about how to launch it with a command, to be a bash question. So, in short, not all "command line" question are bash question. And this one is not. There is nothing specific to bash here. And in fact to programming. You would probably get better answer on [su] or [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com)